# How to stop thread from BroadcastReceiver in onReceive()

Tags: android

The main idea is how to stop running thread from onReceive(),for example if connection is lost stop thread which is making connections to internet?
I have a class that extends BroadcastReceiver and i want to have access on running thread in another class to stop it.

Comment: hmm plz clarify your requirement a lil more...

Comment: Please write how have you created threads receiving in first place. I think only UI thread will receive broadcasts, but I did not test it.